# how to group by desc order in hql

Tags: hql

I have the following table called questions in HQL Hibernate:

1. ID | Name
2. 1  | Bread
3. 2  | Bread
4. 3  | Rise
5. 4  | Rise

I want to select each PRODUT only once and if there are multiple PRODUCT with the same name, select the one of the highest id. So, the expected results:

1. ID | NAME
2. 3  | Bread
3. 4  | Rise

I use the following query:

from Product AS E  group by E.producto

So it selects the first 'Product' it encounters instead of the last one.

Thanks

Comment: There is no need to put appreciation in your posts. If you want to show your appreciation, use votes, if you don't have enough rep to vote yet, don't do anything (or mark answers as "Accepted")

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is almost identical to SQL:

```
select max(p.id), p.name from Product p group by p.name
```

Relevant documentation:

- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-aggregation
- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-grouping